# Statusline wrong column count for multi-byte characters

Tags: vimscript, statusline, counting

I have set this statusline.

```
:set statusline=%c
```

According to `:help statusline`, `%c` means column number.
If the buffer contents is

```
abcdef
éÀ│§õ→
```

and the cursor is on the `f` character, the statusline correctly reports "6".
But if on the arrow character, it reports "12" instead of "6", certainly because it is counting
bytes instead of characters (`éÀ§õ→` are 2 bytes each and `│` is 3 bytes).

The file encoding is correct:

```
:set encoding?
encoding=utf-8
```

Is it possible to workaround that and have the column count instead of the byte count? I have thought of using the `%{ }` construct with the Unix `wc -m` command to count characters, but I cannot devise a plan to put all the pieces together, if it is possible at all.

PS: The `5|` normal mode command correctly moves to the 5th column on both lines.

Comment: One of many sources on the topic, though not the one I remembered: https://hsivonen.fi/string-length/

Comment: Also `:helpgrep virtual column` is enlightening

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it looks the answer is as simple as

```
:set statusline=%v
```

That uses the virtual column number instead of the column number.

Thanks to D. Ben Knoble for pointing me in the right direction.